# CSS transition fade in only the background not the child divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this situation:

```js
setTimeout(function() {


  // Set BG image
  var bg_content = document.querySelector('.content_top');
  bg_content.style.background = "linear-gradient(0deg,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Example_image.svg) no-repeat";
  bg_content.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
  bg_content.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
  bg_content.classList.add("fade-in");

}, 1500);
```

```css
.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.main_header {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.content_top {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_top">
  <div class="main_header"><span class="vertical_line"></span>
    <p data-transkey="main_header_notrans"><span class="tino">Some header</span> <br> some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.content_top` has a `background-image`, which I want to fade in when the page loads, but I do not want the `.main_header` to be affected aswell. Currently this leads to a flicker effect of the text in `.main_header` and looks bad.

Here is a working example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLb5yz9m/)

Comment: Please don't use external code representations like fiddles, codepens etc. **unless the StackOverflow snippet functionality isn't sufficient to demonstrate your issue.** Questions seeking debugging help need to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**.

Comment: I really think you can't set the opacity of a parent without affecting its children. That's in CSS's name : CASCADING Style Sheets. It cascades from parent to children. If you set `opacity:0` to a div, everything that's inside will disappear as well, there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the background to a new div inside of the `.content_top` element. This will create a new layer which we can animate without affecting the content.

Give `.content_top` and `.main_header` a `position: relative` value. This will make the `.content_top` a relative container, and give `.main_header` the possibility to use the `z-index`.

In the snippet below I've added a new element: `.main_bg`. This element will get the background image and the animation.

Give the `.main_bg` element a `position: absolute;`. This will allow you to overlay elements on top of each other, in this case `.main_bg` and `.main_header`.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  // Set BG image
  var bg_content = document.querySelector('.main_bg');
  bg_content.style.background = "linear-gradient(0deg,#000 0,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Example_image.svg) no-repeat";
  bg_content.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
  bg_content.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
  bg_content.classList.add("fade-in");

}, 1500);
```

```css
.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.main_bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main_header {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content_top {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_top">
  <div class="main_bg"></div>
  <div class="main_header"><span class="vertical_line"></span>
    <p data-transkey="main_header_notrans"><span class="tino">Some header</span> <br> some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```